# How to get the Spotify refresh token in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, spotify

In the [web api](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) for `/authorize` a refresh and access token are returned. How can I access/ receive a refresh token similar to what is returned in `/authorize`?

Something like `SPTAuth.defaultInstance().refreshToken`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a URL scheme for your app. Something like:

`appName://SpotifyAuthentication`

Then when you register your dev account with Spotify, you need to enter that as the redirect URI. When you make the request on the device (`GET https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=.....&response_type=code& redirect_uri=appName%3A%2F%2FSpotifyAuthentication&.....`), it will call this URI automatically and will call: `application:openURL:options:` in `AppDelegate`.

The URL query string will contain your auth token. IE: `appName://SpotifyAuthentication?authToken=someToken`.

Comment: Is the `authToken` the same as the WebAPI `refresh_token`?

Comment: @user25093; It is not the same. You will have to make the request to `POST https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token` to exchange your `AuthToken` for an `RefreshToken`. Same logic applies.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion but I'd like to clear a few things up. [Is this](https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/Classes/SPTAuth.html), `SPTAuth`, what I would be receiving back? Per [step four](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) I need a `grant_type`, `code`, and `redirect_uri`. Does just posting `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token` with the `AuthToken` return a `refresh_token`? How do I access the `AuthToken`?

Comment: @user25093  it's in the query string.

Comment: What query string? And can I just post the query string in its entirety?

Comment: @user25093; The specification says: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/  in section #3. `If the user has accepted your request, the response query string contains the following parameters" code & state`.  As stated, it will come in the query string. That query string will be in your AppDelegate's URL parameter of the OpenURL function.

Comment: The URL contains `myApp://returnAfterLogin/#access_token=77777&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600`. I think that link only applies to web calls?

Comment: In my session I get a 'encryptedRefreshToken`, is there a way to decrypt this?